# Recommendations for Scientific Dissertation Style Guides

Tags: discussion

Just wondering if anyone can recommend any good free online style guides for theses and dissertations, especially for the sciences. Looking for something authoritative and that really gets into the detailed nitty-gritty. Something maybe like the *Chicago Manual of Style* but for scientific dissertations.

Comment: The "Style" answer at the linked question contains recommendations for scientific works. Adding more there would always be good, if there are any missing.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Greatly helpful.
However, at that page, both the AMA Manual and Scientific Style and Format are listed but they both require a subscription. 
In searching online, I see that many individual universities provide their own version of a dissertation style guide, but because there are so many of these, it is difficult to know which is comprehensive and authoritative.

Comment: @curious-proofreader None is comprehensive and they are all equally authoritative for a member of the public. If you are writing a thesis or dissertation, adhere to the guidance provided by your institution or department.

Comment: The existence of a general list of style English reference works is not the same as asking *if* such an authoritative work exists. This fits the Q/A nature and quick-reference to answer format of the StackExchange far *better* than that link which *does not answer the question*. 

(A: Such authoritative standards do not exist. The publishers ultimately set their standards. As such, they publish their style rules. Fields sometimes adopt common standards, usually by adopting those of a high-power journal.)

Comment: **Consult your dissertation supervisor** is the only good answer. There is no general reference. Every university, and often every department, has its own traditions, requirements, and affordances. If you want to see what a dissertation looks like, read one. There are thousands of them on the Web, in all kinds of fields.